# apple numbers Filling data into a table using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, numbers, automation

I have a document on numbers with 3 sheets.

- 1-data entry table (based on the "data" sheet).
- 2-copy dada table with:

--   I.an additional column containing the following formula

```
        if(reference no of data entery=reference no of this row;1;0)
```

--  II.filter table, greater than 0

- 3-data table

I want to use Applescript in order to fill the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2

```
tell application "Numbers" to ¬
     tell table 2 of sheet 1 of document (1)
          set getRef to the value of cell "A1"
          set fileinfolder to the value of cell "A2"
          set Outof to the value of cell "A3"
          set valqora to the value of cell "A9"
          set valqno to the value of cell "A10"
          set valQout to the value of cell "A11"
          set valcomment to the value of cell "A13"
          set valnoclue to the value of cell "A14"
          set valhard to the value of cell "A15"
          set valok to the value of cell "A16"
          set valeasy to the value of cell "A17"

end tell

tell application "Numbers" to ¬
    tell table 1 of sheet 3 of document (1)
        set the value of cell "K2" to the value of fileinfolder
        set the value of cell "L2" to the value of Outof
        set the value of cell "M2" to the value of valqora
        set the value of cell "N2" to the value of valqno
        set the value of cell "O2" to the value of valQout
        set the value of cell "P2" to the value of valcomment
        set the value of cell "Q2" to the value of valnoclue
        set the value of cell "R2" to the value of valhard
        set the value of cell "S2" to the value of valok
        set the value of cell "T2" to the value of valeasy

end tell
```

i keep recicing  Syntax Error- Can’t get value of true

Answer (score 1):

For your second block of assignments, remove the second 'the value of' from each line so that they look like this:

```
set the value of cell "K2" to fileinfolder
```

That second 'value' is redundant.

As an aside, the error is peculiar in that it should probably be a 'script error' that can't get the value of '1.0', for example. So whichever cell is generating the error is probably indicating to the script that it's a boolean or something. But this isn't the source of your problem, just a symptom.

NB To test this, I simply used a column of numbers ranging from 1 to 17 to supply the first block of assignments.